# Need more info on logging and debugging framework using Selenium

Tags: selenium, test-automation-framework

Need more info on logging and debugging framework for Selenium

I have referred a  few of the following resources below:

http://www.infostretch.com/QA/selenium-framework.php

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/10-tips-proper-application-logging.html

Answer (score 3):

I've used log4j. Development of log4j [seems to have gone dormant](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/roadmap.html).

These days I use the [Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4j) API](http://www.slf4j.org/), with [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as the implementation. Selenium internally uses another logging API and implementation (Apache commons logging, I think), but SLF4j offers mechanisms to reroute those other logging calls through your chosen SLF4j implementation.

One nice feature of logback: You can log each test class's output to its own log file. Another: You can write logs in HTML format, which makes them easy to post to intranets where anyone can access them in a browser.

Comment: I agree that your link to log4j 1.2 implies the project is dormant, but there is also a log4j 2.0 project (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/index.html) and there is activity on the log4j mailing list (http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-dev/201201.mbox/browser).

Answer (score 1):

The most common logging framework for Java is [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/).  A Google search will turn up many references, a few tutorials, and even a few books.

Answer (score 0):

From previous questions of yours, it would appear as though you're doing most of your automation in Java.  I'd recommend looking into a logging framework, or, create one for yourself.  I'm not sure about Java, but, in .NET, I'd use tools like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).  To create your own, all that you really need is to print your desired content and exceptions to a log file.  Just a regular old textfile has always worked well for me.